# Was every programmer at Microsoft given a copy of Code Complete?

Tags: books, microsoft

Did, at some point, every new programmer at Microsoft get given a copy of [Code Complete by Steve McConnell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619670)?

Comment: Questions should reference a [notable claim](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable). Can you reference a source for this claim? I've never heard it before.

Comment: @Johnny I am sorry, this was my question exactly...

Comment: I Have heard the claim before.  I think it actually came from Steve Balhmers book but I have never read it.

Comment: Steve Ballmer hasn't written a book. Do you mean "Bad Boy Ballmer: The Man Who Rules Microsoft"?

Comment: @rick, where did YOU hear the claim?

Comment: I was thinking of "Microsoft Rebooted: How Bill Gates and Steve Ballmer Reinvented Their Company" but again I havent actually read it just been told some of the stuff in it and that it was a must read... yet i haven't read it and the world has not stopped turning so must is hyperbole here.  Though I have read Code Complete and thought it was worth the read.

Comment: By the way, big difference between "every programmer" and 'every new programmer".

Comment: @Chad: My Amazon and Google Books searches of the book contents find no references.